# Binding adapter for dimension resource in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-resources, android-databinding

I have an ImageView for which I wanted to write a custom binding adapter

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_list_picture"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/normal_475"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/item_list_secondary_text"
        android:contentDescription="@{listItemViewModel.primaryText}"
        android:padding="@dimen/normal_100"
        android:displayImageUrl="@{listItemViewModel.pictureUrl}"
        android:placeHolderDrawable="@{@drawable/ic_baseline_image_24}"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/normal_475"
        android:specificWidth="@dimen/normal_475"
        android:goneUnless="@{listItemViewModel.pictureUrl != null}" />
```

The dimension for `specificWidth` is defined in `dimens.xml` as

```
<dimen name="normal_475">77dp</dimen>
```

And finally the `BindingAdapter.kt` file has the following code:

```
@BindingAdapter("android:displayImageUrl", "android:placeHolderDrawable", "android:specificWidth")
fun loadImage(view: ImageView, displayImageUrl: String?, placeHolderDrawable: Drawable, @DimenRes width: Int) {
    if (!displayImageUrl.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        Picasso.get().load(displayImageUrl).placeholder(placeHolderDrawable)
            .resize(view.context.resources.getDimensionPixelSize(width), view.context.resources.getDimensionPixelSize(width)).centerCrop().into(view)
    } else {
        view.setImageDrawable(placeHolderDrawable)
    }
}
```

If I use the binding adapter's `loadImage` without the `specificWidth` everything works. Otherwise, I get the following error

```
ERROR:C:\dev\projects\myapp\app\src\main\res\layout\item_list.xml:69: AAPT: error: attribute android:specificWidth not found.
```

What is the problem here? How can I get the specific width from the dimension defined? I also tried to add `android:layout_width` to the binding adapter instead of my custom `android:specificWidth`, but it doesn't work either. The possibility to use `android:layout_width` value in dp would be even better as I need to get the size given for the `ImageView` to resize the downloaded image from `pictureUrl`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `android:specificWidth`'s type is resource you need to set it like below:

```
android:specificWidth="@{R.dimen.normal_475}"
```

also you need to import `R` in your data tag:

```
<import type="your.package.name.R" />
```

Or if you want to pass the dimen value you need to change your `bindingAdapter` `specificWidth` input to this:

```
fun loadImage(
view: ImageView,
displayImageUrl: String?,
placeHolderDrawable: Drawable,
width: Float // change the type to float and clear the `@dimenRes` annotation
```

also change your xml to:

```
 android:specificWidth="@{@dimen/normal_475}" // you need to pass the value in data-binding format
```

By the way you can also ignore this `android:specificWidth` attribute as you said and instead read the value from the view's width and height. you just need to do it on `view.post{}` to make sure the view is rendered and its size is valid. so your `bindingAdapter` fun would be something like this:

```
@BindingAdapter("android:displayImageUrl", "android:placeHolderDrawable")
fun loadImage(view: ImageView, displayImageUrl: String?, placeHolderDrawable: Drawable) {
    view.post {
        if (!displayImageUrl.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            Picasso.get().load(displayImageUrl).placeholder(placeHolderDrawable)
                .resize(
                    view.width,
                    view.height
                ).centerCrop().into(view)
        } else {
            view.setImageDrawable(placeHolderDrawable)
        }
    }
}
```

If you had any questions or I didn't get your problem well please don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was to define the specific width as `android:specificWidth="@{@dimen/normal_475}"`.